# In linux, find and replace the salary from L3 to Employee files in all occurrences within a directory

Tags: linux, shell

In linux, find and replace the salary from L3 to Employee files in all occurrences within a directory

**L3values.txt**

```
Emp id | emp name | salary

1001 | Raghu | 12000

1002 | Geetha | 18000
```

**Employeefile1.txt**

```
Emp id | emp name | Age | Address| salary

1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 10000

1002 | Geetha | 30 | some address | 15000
```

**Employeefile2.txt**

```
Emp id | emp name | Age | Address| salary

1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 10000

1002 | Geetha | 30 | some address | 15000

1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 10000
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gawk -F' \\| ' 'BEGIN {OFS=" | "} NR==FNR {id[$1]=$3; next} $0 { print $1,$2,$3,$4,id[$1] > FILENAME ".tmp" } ENDFILE {system("mv " FILENAME ".tmp " FILENAME " 2>/dev/null")}' values.txt file1.txt file2.txt
```

[Edit]

First of all, edit the first line for both `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. Change this:

```
 Emp id | emp name | Age | Address| salary
```

to

```
Emp id | emp name | Age | Address | salary
```

Or you can run this command:

```
$ gawk -F'\\|' 'BEGIN {OFS=" | "}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sub(/^ */,"",$(i)); sub(/ *$/,"",$(i))}print $0 > FILENAME ".tmp"} ENDFILE {system("mv " FILENAME ".tmp " FILENAME) }' values.txt file1.txt file2.txt
```

And here's the output I got:

**file1.txt**

```
Emp id | emp name | Age | Address | salary
1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 12000
1002 | Geetha | 30 | some address | 18000
```

**file2.txt**

```
Emp id | emp name | Age | Address | salary
1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 12000
1002 | Geetha | 30 | some address | 18000
1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 12000
```

Or you can use this if you want blanks between each line.

```
$ gawk -F' \\| ' 'BEGIN {OFS=" | "} NR==FNR {id[$1]=$3; next} $0 { print $1,$2,$3,$4,id[$1]"\n" > FILENAME ".tmp" } ENDFILE {system("mv " FILENAME ".tmp " FILENAME " 2>/dev/null")}' values.txt file1.txt file2.txt
```

**file1.txt**

```
Emp id | emp name | Age | Address | salary

1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 12000

1002 | Geetha | 30 | some address | 18000
```

**file2.txt**

```
Emp id | emp name | Age | Address | salary

1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 12000

1002 | Geetha | 30 | some address | 18000

1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 12000
```

Comment: Working fine for Raghu. But Geetha value's are getting blank

Comment: Working fine for Raghu. But Geetha value's are getting blank 

1001 | Raghu | 25 | some address | 12000

1002 | Geetha | 30 | some address |

Comment: Be sure that each field is separated by `` | `` (space,vertical bar,space).